# PHP: What's the best way to type hint a class in an inherited method from a concrete class' parent class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Yeah I know, that title is a mouthful :)

Code will make this way more digestible:

```
namespace AbstractLevel;    

abstract class Bar 
{
    public function addFoo(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}

namespace AbstractLevel\ConcreteLevel;

class Bar extends \AbstractLevel\Bar
{
    public function addFoo(Foo $foo)
    {
        parent::addFoo($foo);
    }
}
```

The above code should receive a runtime notice when instantiating the `AbstractLevel\ConcreteLevel\Bar` class because the `addFoo()` method is typehinting for a different class than its parent's method of the same name.

Is there any way to ensure that the `AbstractLevel\ConcreteLevel\Bar::addFoo()` typehints for the class `AbstractLevel\ConcreteLevel\Foo` instead of `AbstractLevel\Foo`?

Comment: I think this is not possible as an overwritten method allways has to follow it's parents class signature. Sady PHP is not capable of overloading.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to ensure...

You can add the absolute path to the typehinted class:

```
public function addFoo(\AbstractLevel\ConcreteLevel\Foo $foo)
```

I'm currently not 100% sure about the keyword `abstract`,

you might need to put it there in the first class:

```
abstract class Bar 
{
    public abstract function addFoo(Foo $foo)
```

Comment: Using an abstract method you would not be able to implement the logic currently contained in `AbstractLevel\Bar::addFoo()`.